# jQuery Select2 used from parent.window to child iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-select2

Good day all.
I have a html page, `page.html`, which loads an iframe, called `iframe.html`.
I have `Select2` into page.html and there is a `<select class='selectme'>` into `iframe.html`.

I'm using this js to fire Select2 FROM `page.html`:

```
var jFrame = function (selector) { return $(selector, $("iframe").contents()); };
OurBigWrapper = {
    "setup":{
        "init":function(){
            console.log("wrapper,setup,init");
            var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

            jFrame(".countries").select2(
                {
                  data: data /*,
                  formatSelection : this.formatSelection.bind(this)*/
                }
            );  

        }
    }
}
```

while on the iframe.html page the code is like this:

```
<select class="countries">

    </select>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            parent.OurBigWrapper.setup.init();
        }); 

    </script>
```

What I obtain is that the Select gets the data properly, but once clicked, the select only "change" the little arrow on the right, indicating the "opened option panel" but no option actually shows up.
[image: not clicked]

[image: clicked]

interesting enough, if I delete the select2 css, this is what I obtain:

[image: nocss]

and here, clicking on the select and selecting another option, is what I see:

[image: nocss2]

someone has any kind of clue of what is going on and how I can prevent it to happen?

Comment: Are options there in `<select>` when seen by DOM inspector?

Comment: Yes the injection works fine.

Comment: are you making sure the child page is loaded before you make the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: I copied and pasted your code inside a button click and it worked for me. Is there a timing issue?]

```
            <script>
                $(function ($) {
                    $("button").on("click", function (evt) {
                var jFrame = function (selector) { return $(selector, $("iframe").contents()); };

                var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];
                jFrame(".selectme").select2(
                    {
                        data: data
                    }
                );

                    });
                })
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe id="myframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
            <button type="button">click</button>
        </body>
```

and

```
    <body>
        <select class="selectme"></select> i
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's a bit different from my environment, I'll post it asap, but the idea is pretty the same, can't figure out why isn't working for me :/

Comment: I've updated the question to insert a code more similar to the one I'm using on the real case.
as you may notice, the select2 calls are "wrapped" inside an object, could be ths the problem? the context of the calls?